# How to use custom callout for annotation when using Google maps in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uiview

I am using `Google Maps` in `iOS app` .So far I am able to show user location on the map. I am trying to use a custom callout when a annotation is clicked.

This is what I have done so far.

1] Created a`XIB` file and assigned a class name to it of a `UIView` subclass.

2] Used markerInfoWindow delegate method as below.

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    CustomGoogleCallOut *view =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomGoogleCallOut" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    view.callOutImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.png"];
    view.callOutTitleLabel .text = @"title";
    view.callOutUserName.text = @"Mario";
    return view;
}
```

However I am not able to see call out.What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing delegate. in h file

```
: UIViewController<GMSMapViewDelegate>
```

in .m file

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```